# Expand div inside table cell like dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing list of checkboxes in a table cell. Defaultly it has 
overflow property set to 'hidden' and height set so only first element is visible.

After a onclick action I would like it to expand over a table without resizing the table row. 
Just like a dropdown menu is working.

Is it anyhow possible?

Code:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.height == '100px') {
e.style.height = '22px';
e.style.overflow = 'hidden';
e.scrollTop = 0;
}
else {
e.style.height = '100px';
e.style.overflow = 'scroll';
}
};
```

```css
td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
#id {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p><a onclick="toggle_visibility('test');">Click here to toggle size of div</a></p>
<p>

<table>
<tbody class="data">
<tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
    
    </td>
    <td><div id="test" style="height: 22px; overflow: hidden;">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox">1</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">2</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">3</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox">4</input></li>
        </ul>
    </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123</td>
<td>456</td>
<td>789</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>000</td>
<td>000</td>
<td>000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dmyfskj/

Comment: use position property.. in div containing checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set **DIV** position property to ***absolute***

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6dmyfskj/1/  
now its upto you how you fit it in table cell.. use CSS and  position it using top and left property...